# Java, pixels in a given letter of a particular Font

Tags: java, fonts, pixel

How can I determine how many pixels are in a specific letter of a specific Font in Java?

Comment: The number of pixels in a character is dependent on what attributes (italic, bold, etc.), what size, and whether or not anti-aliasing is being performed.  You might be able to render the font (in white) in a graphics object and count the number of non-black pixels you find.

Comment: What would you do with that information? Define "pixel" (think about subpixel antialiasing, and even antialiasing in general). And anyway, whatever you try to measure, it will certainly depend on the font rendering engine - something of which Java may not even be conscious. (look at the difference in Windows with or without ClearType!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the font loaded as a [`Font`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) object, you can create a new [`FontMetrics`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) object (or one of its children if your graphics toolkit has one) and its [`charWidth(char ch)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#charWidth%28char%29) method to determine its size.  The units aren't listed in the manual, but I'm assuming pixels.

Likewise, there's a [`stringWidth`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#stringWidth%28java.lang.String%29) method to get the width of an entire `String`.